# calibre.exe on Windows 7 tries to phone home every time it starts up. How can I make it stop?

Tags: calibre

[image: calibre phones home]

I use Calibre (https://calibre-ebook.com/) to read e-books on Windows 7. However, even after disabling notifications for updates and downloads of metadata, it still seems to phone home every time it starts up (see the attached image). How can I disable this, please?

Comment: If there is no option to disable it, then you could block the port is uses, in your firewall.  In the end without knowing what is being sent out, its hard to answer this question, outside of verify there really isn't an option to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That IP Address is used by calibre to collect anonymous usage statistics, it redirects to:
https://calibre-ebook.com/dynamic/calibre-usage

There doesn't appear to be a method to configure calibre to not send this information, so you will have to block it in your firewall.

In windows 7 you can add a rule to the firewall to block a specific IP address pretty easily:

> a. Click Start
>  b. Type "firewall" and click on "Windows Firewall with
>   Advanced Security" that will appear under "Programs."
>  c. Select
>   "Outbound Rules" on the left panel of the firewall window.
>  d.
>   Right-click and choose "New Rule" from the pop-up menu.
>  e. Select
>   the radio button "Custom" and click "Next."
>  f. Select the radio
>   button "All Programs" and click "Next." Then click "Next" again.
>   g. Select the radio button "These IP addresses" in the field "Remote
>   IP addresses. Click "Add" and type the IP address you wish to block in
>   the field. Click "OK" and then "Next."
>  h. Select "Block the
>   connection" and click "Next."
>  i. Type a descriptive name for this
>   Windows firewall rule. Click "Next" and then "Finish" to create the
>   rule that blocks the IP address.

Instructions pulled from:
from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-block-outbound-and-inbound-specific-ip/d42c58d0-2693-4a10-a4e4-331b7d041036